# ActionView::Template::Error - undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I'm trying to pass a local variable to the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => 'bar/search_bar', :locals => { :foo => "1111" }  %>
```

but when I try to access the `foo` variable in the partial

```
<p> <%= foo %> </p>
```

I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<#<Class:0x007f32249423e0>:0x007f3230b839b8>):
```

I'm using `rails 3.2`, I also followed some posts but they couldn't help either.

Comment: @Trip That's wrong, that isn't how you access locals. The syntax in both snippets of code is exactly correct, there is something else at play here.

Comment: He could also try `<%= render :partial => 'bar/search_bar', :foo => "1111" %>` I believe..

Comment: @Trip Also no. The two syntaxes that can work here are `render 'bar/search_bar', foo: '1111` *or* `render partial: 'bar/search_bar', locals: { foo:  '1111'} }`. You use `:parial`/`:locals`, or you just use a string and implicit `:locals` hash.

Comment: Maybe you render this partial in few places and in someplace you forgot to pass the local parameter?

Comment: I sometimes ran into this problem when accessing the local variable in the very first line of the partial. I don't really know why this should be a problem but my debugger confirmed it. Might be worth a try if your ´<p>´ line is the very first one...

Comment: @KappaNossi: I placed it at the very bottom, still the same.

Comment: Does the _search_bar.html.erb partial pull in any other partials? Also, can you put up the stacktrace? That will probably help

Comment: is it possible that you render the wrong partial?
`<%= render :partial => 'bar/search_bar' %>` in an other file?

Comment: @rainkinz: thanks, I was rendering another partial via javascript. problem resolved. many thanks.